# Laravel 6: redirect with variables AND message - not working

Tags: php, laravel, variables, redirect, multiple-variable-return

i am trying to redirect using a function in my main controller with both variables and a message.

The message code is fine and is usually displayed by ->with('abo', 'messagetext').
The Problem is that not both types are redirected, only the variables (without the message) :(

---

The goal is to redirect the following variables: suchString, userId, suche

```
public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $suchString = $request->input('suchString');
        $userId = $request->input('userId');
        Subscribe::create([
            'abo_string' => $suchString,
            'userid' => $userId
        ]);
            $suche = Document::where( 'title', 'LIKE', '%' . $suchString . '%' )
                                ->orWhere( 'category', 'LIKE', '%' . $suchString . '%' )
                                ->orWhere( 'description', 'LIKE', '%' . $suchString . '%' )
                                ->get();
        $users = User::all();
        return view('pages.search')->with('abo', 'messagetext');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the `compact()` method to redirect your variable.

```
 session()->flash( 'abo', 'Your message' );
 return view('pages.search', compact('suchString', 'userId', 'suche' ));
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply :) is there a way to add the message too? I am trying to return both

Comment: @Dodo43 If you want to pass the message then add a new variable into `compact()` method

Comment: @Dodo43 Logically this latter approach could get rather unwieldy if you needed to pass along more than two variables. You can save some typing by using PHP's `compact()` function:

Comment: i also tried your approach, but the example message is not shown after the call of the view :/ but also no error message tho..

Comment: @Dodo43 How you have retrieved "message text" into view? Also other variable accessible or not? Like `dd($suchString)` . Thanks for tried my solution.

Comment: thats the way, the message should be displayed in the search view; i am not really an expert at messages and laravel:
 ```@if ($message = Session::get('abo'))
                         <div class="alert alert-success alert-block abo-box">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                         <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                         </div>
                    @endif```

Comment: @Dodo43 Send a message into session use `session()->flash( 'abo', 'Your Message' );` I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `view()` not a `redirect()`

And you can also chain `with()` as much as you like.

```
    return redirect()->route('pages.search')
        ->with('abo', 'messagetext')
        ->with('suche', $suche)
        ->with('userId', $userId)
        ->with('suchString', $suchString);
```

Is likely what you want.

These will all be in the session on your next page view.

Comment: somehow the message is display, but the variables are not displayed. Mabe its the input, i dont know :/